# Could not find a declaration file for module 'firebase-tools'

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am writing my first cloud function for Firebase and it requires the `firebase-tools` module. I've installing it by adding it to my dependencies in the package.json file and running `npm install`.

Then I tried to import it using `import * as tools from 'firebase-tools';`, but I get this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'firebase-tools'. 'c:/Users/LENOVO/Nouveau dossier/functions/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/firebase-tools` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'firebase-tools';

I also tried running `npm install @types/firebase-tools`, but apparently it does not exist and I'm not sure what I should put in the (.d.ts) file for this module.

So I'm asking if there's another solution and if I need to create a (.d.ts) file what should I put there beside `declare module 'firebase-tools`.

Comment: Hey, firebase-tools is a command line interface tool and not be included in package.json. Just run "npm install -g firebase-tools" to install the tools. And now use "firebase init" to create a new firebase project. Complete documentation is present [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli)

Comment: Hey Akshay , thanks for your answer. But I already did that and still it doesn't work. I included the dependency in my package.json file because it's what they did in this link:  https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/master/firestore/solution-deletes/functions/package.json. And it is said that it can be used as a module over here too : https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools. I'm not sure what I'm missing, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you please share what is it that is not working? What do you need this package for?

Comment: When I try to import the package I get an error saying that there is no declaration file for the package. And I'm trying to write a cloud function for Firebase that does the deletion of a collection and its subcollections for Firestore and from what I found this requires this package. When I open the lib folder of the package that I've installed there's a folder called 'firestore' and a JavaScript file called 'delete' , so i guess that what I need in my case.The other packages has there own declaration files with the extension (.d.ts) but there's none for this one.

Comment: Hey everyone, the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#cloud_function) clearly say we need to use firebase-tools inside a cloud function. But since my cloud functions are TS, I'm also confused on how I can execute this.

Answer (score 9):

I have same problem, too.
The problem is that firebase-tools modules don't have (.d.ts)file.
I found that we have 3 solutions in this situation.

- install @types/xxx ←you have done, but it doesn't exist.
- self made (.d.ts)file ←I don't know very well.
- use "require" instead of "import" ←I solved this way.The modules are
  imported as "any" type implicitly.

when ts-lint alert you "[tslint] require statement not part of an import statement (no-var-requires)", you can ignore it by comment "// tslint:disable-next-line:no-var-requires"

Thank you for reading.

Comment: do you know why it doen'st have a .d.ts file? Why don't they include typescript support by default for all their projects?

Comment: @Ruben based on the discussion on their GitHub issue it seems the amount of runtime code-gen makes a type definition file difficult to produce.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2378

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved this problem was:

First of all, add `"firebase-tools": "^9.10.0"` to your `package.json` under `/functions` directory, like so:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
"firebase-tools": "^9.10.0"
},
```

Then, in your function code use `require` instead of `import`, like so:

`const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');`

Answer (score 1):

try to add `"noImplicitAny": false,` to `tsconfig.json`