# Could not find a declaration file for module 'firebase-tools', despite installing and requiring

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have tried several different methods for installing Firebase-Tools

```
npm install firebase-tools

npm i --save-dev @types/firebase-tools

npm install -g firebase-tools
```

But still when I add:

```
const firebase_tools = require("firebase-tools")
```

to my project, I get an error when deploying:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'firebase_tools'

in my Visual Studio Code.

I have tried following the below link, but their response was to use require, which I already am.

[Could not find a declaration file for module 'firebase-tools'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443687/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-firebase-tools)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
npm install -s firebase-tools
```

Since your error happens when deploying, I am led to believe your `package.json` may not contain the firebase-tools dependency. You need to run the `npm install` command with the `-s` flag in order for it to be saved in the `package.json`

Comment: I think you're corrrect RE package.json, as I cannot see the dependency there. But I just ran this and there was no change to my package.json file at all, despite everything going ahead smoothly.

Is there a way to manually force it into package.json?

Comment: You can add the dependency manually in your `package.json` by adding `"firebase-tools": "^9.2.2",` inside the `"dependencies": { },` field